# Not able to install textract using !pip install textract

Tags: python, pip

I have been trying to install textract using command:
!pip install textract, but getting below errors:

```
Collecting textract
Requirement already satisfied: docx2txt==0.6 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from textract) (0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete==1.8.2 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from textract) (1.8.2)
Collecting six==1.10.0 (from textract)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/0a/b6723e1bc4c516cb687841499455a8505b44607ab535be01091c0f24f079/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting EbookLib==0.15 (from textract)
Collecting pocketsphinx==0.1.3 (from textract)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/5f/a968e5d53d25e32deb78c3e169fd8612ecf53cc76e32cb40e19be35696af/pocketsphinx-0.1.3.tar.bz2
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4==4.5.3 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from textract) (4.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: SpeechRecognition==3.6.3 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from textract) (3.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==2.3.0 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from textract) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-pptx==0.6.5 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from textract) (0.6.5)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd==1.0.0 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from textract) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from EbookLib==0.15->textract) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: XlsxWriter>=0.5.7 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-pptx==0.6.5->textract) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=2.6.1 in /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-pptx==0.6.5->textract) (5.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Building wheel for pocketsphinx (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/backup/mltmp/pip-install-k3hazve3/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /backup/mltmp/pip-wheel-7t5e7pu4 --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build_ext
  building 'sphinxbase._ad' extension
  swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c
  swig -python -modern -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad.i
  unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
  error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py clean for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
spacy 2.0.12 has requirement regex==2017.4.5, but you'll have regex 2018.7.11 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: six, EbookLib, pocketsphinx, textract
  Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx ... error
    Complete output from command /home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/backup/mltmp/pip-install-k3hazve3/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /backup/mltmp/pip-record-ws03agmf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._ad' extension
    swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c
    swig -python -modern -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad.i
    unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/UGI/akedia/.conda/envs/at3deploy/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/backup/mltmp/pip-install-k3hazve3/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /backup/mltmp/pip-record-ws03agmf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /backup/mltmp/pip-install-k3hazve3/pocketsphinx/
```

Comment: `unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory` => Do you have swig installed?

Comment: Check out the edited answer, and comment if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html), you cannot directly install it as `pip install tesseract` you will need to execute the commands based on your os, now based on your directory architecture I am assuming that it is a Linux system, and since you used `!pip` I believe you are using Ipyhton notebook or jupyter shell to install this,
 In which case you will need to run it in two parts, first run

```
!apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev antiword unrtf poppler-utils pstotext tesseract-ocr flac ffmpeg lame libmad0 libsox-fmt-mp3 sox libjpeg-dev swig
```

And then run

```
!apt-get install libpulse-dev
!pip install textract
```

And you get, Apparently you also need `libpulse-dev` which is not mentioned in the official installation guide.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpulse-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 104 kB of archives.
After this operation, 714 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2 [22.1 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpulse-dev amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2 [81.5 kB]
Fetched 104 kB in 1s (192 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 119263 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpulse-mainloop-glib0_1%3a11.1-1ubuntu7.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpulse-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpulse-dev_1%3a11.1-1ubuntu7.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulse-dev:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Setting up libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Setting up libpulse-dev:amd64 (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Collecting textract
Requirement already satisfied: docx2txt==0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete==1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (1.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: EbookLib==0.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: python-pptx==0.6.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (0.6.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4==4.5.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (4.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet==2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd==1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (1.0.0)
Collecting pocketsphinx==0.1.3 (from textract)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/5f/a968e5d53d25e32deb78c3e169fd8612ecf53cc76e32cb40e19be35696af/pocketsphinx-0.1.3.tar.bz2
Requirement already satisfied: SpeechRecognition==3.6.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from textract) (3.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from EbookLib==0.15->textract) (4.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=2.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-pptx==0.6.5->textract) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: XlsxWriter>=0.5.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-pptx==0.6.5->textract) (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from Pillow>=2.6.1->python-pptx==0.6.5->textract) (0.46)
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Building wheel for pocketsphinx (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/38/80/4f/ddc3e8c2b788f2c7f1d625ae870f6bafd3038ff04a3445a2f8
Successfully built pocketsphinx
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx, textract
Successfully installed pocketsphinx-0.1.3 textract-1.6.1
```

Comment: Do you even understand what you have copied there? If so, why would you even separate that `apt-get` line like this?

Comment: @NilsWerner I saw the Installation guide and got a little confused on it being on the second line and flac being a command line tool itself, thanks for pointing my obvious mistakes, should not have made that, also there was a dependency missing in the official guide due to which it will fail install, added that as well, again thanks for pointing it out.